# XSL: Just the filename without the path

Tags: xslt, substring, concatenation

I'm new in XSL programming and I guess it is a simple question:
How can I get the filename without the path?
At the moment my code looks like this and I get the whole path:
**Result.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<All_Results>
    <Result>
      <id>1</id>
      <workid>144</workid>
      <rank>100000000</rank>
      <title>Test Dokument</title>
      <author_multival>Test</author_multival>
      <author>Test</author>
      <size>34185</size>
      <url>https://test.test.com/docs/globalit/Lists/Documents/Datumtest/Test.docx</url>
      <urlEncoded>https%3A%2F%2Ftest%2Etest%2Ecom%2Fdocs%2Fglobalit%2FLists%2FDocuments%2FDatumtest%2FTest%2Edocx</urlEncoded>
      <description></description>
      <write>5/3/2013</write>
      <sitename>https://test.test.com/docs/globalit/Lists/Documents/Datumtest</sitename>
      <collapsingstatus>0</collapsingstatus>
      <hithighlightedsummary>Noch mehr text Noch mehr text  <ddd /> </hithighlightedsummary>
      <hithighlightedproperties>
        <HHTitle>Test Dokument</HHTitle>
        <HHUrl>https://test.test.com/docs/globalit/Lists/Documents/Datumtest/Test.docx</HHUrl>
      </hithighlightedproperties>
      <contentclass>STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary</contentclass>
      <isdocument>True</isdocument>
      <picturethumbnailurl></picturethumbnailurl>
      <serverredirectedurl>https://test.test.com/docs/globalit/_layouts/WordViewer.aspx?id=/docs/globalit/Lists/Documents/Datumtest/Test.docx&amp;DefaultItemOpen=1</serveedirectedurl> 
<doclanguage>German</doclanguage>
  <doctitle>Test</doctitle>
  <docauthor>Team</docauthor>
  <revisiondate>5/3/2013</revisiondate>
  <filename>Test.docx</filename>
  <fileextension>DOCX</fileextension>
  <imageurl imageurldescription="Microsoft Word">/_layouts/images/icdocx.png</imageurl>
</Result>
</All_Results>
```

**result.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="TotalResults" />
  <xsl:template match="NumberOfResults" />

  <xsl:template name="DisplayString">
    <xsl:param name="str" />
    <xsl:if test='string-length($str) &gt; 0'>
      <xsl:value-of select="$str" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="HitHighlighting">
    <xsl:param name="hh" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$hh"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="ResultPreviewToolTip">
    <xsl:param name="contentclass" />
    <xsl:param name="picturethumbnailurl" />
    <xsl:param name="url" />
    <xsl:param name="title" />
    <xsl:param name="hithighlightedsummary" />
    <xsl:param name="description" />
    <xsl:param name="version" />

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$contentclass[. = 'STS_ListItem_PictureLibrary'] and $picturethumbnailurl[. != '']">
        <div>
          <a href="{$url}" title="{$title}">
            <img src="{$picturethumbnailurl}" alt="" />
          </a>
        </div>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="contains( $url, 'jpg' ) or contains( $url, 'jpeg' ) or contains( $url, 'gif' ) or contains( $url, 'JPG' ) or contains( $url, 'JPEG' ) or contains( $url, 'GIF' )">
        <div>
          <img src="/_layouts/AssetUploader.aspx?Size=Medium&amp;ImageUrl={$url}" alt="" />
        </div>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <div>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$hithighlightedsummary[. != '']">
              <b>Preview:</b>
              <br/>
              <xsl:call-template name="HitHighlighting">
                <xsl:with-param name="hh" select="$hithighlightedsummary" />
              </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$description[. != '']">
              <b>Preview:</b>
              <br/>
              <xsl:value-of select="$description"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              No preview available
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
          <xsl:call-template name="DisplayString">
            <xsl:with-param name="str" select="$version" />
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="'Version: '" />
            <xsl:with-param name="stringcolor" select="'#808080'" />
          </xsl:call-template>

        </div >
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Result">
    <xsl:variable name="tdClass">
      <xsl:if test="(position() mod 2 = 0)">
        <xsl:value-of select="'even'" />
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="(position() mod 2 = 1)">
        <xsl:value-of select="'odd'" />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>

    <tr>
      <td class="{$tdClass}">
        <a href="#" class="tooltip">
          <img>
            <xsl:attribute name="src">
              <xsl:value-of select="imageurl"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
          </img>
          <span>
            <xsl:call-template name="ResultPreviewToolTip">
              <xsl:with-param name="contentclass" select="contentclass" />
              <xsl:with-param name="description" select="description" />
              <xsl:with-param name="hithighlightedsummary" select="hithighlightedsummary" />
              <xsl:with-param name="picturethumbnailurl" select="picturethumbnailurl" />
              <xsl:with-param name="title" select="title" />
              <xsl:with-param name="url" select="url" />
              <xsl:with-param name="version" select="version" />
            </xsl:call-template>
          </span>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a>
          <xsl:attribute name="href">
            <xsl:value-of select="url" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:value-of select="filename"/>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td class="{$tdClass}">
        <a>
          <xsl:attribute name="href">
            <xsl:value-of select="url" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="doctitle != ''">
              <xsl:value-of select="doctitle"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </a>
      </td>      
      <td class="{$tdClass}">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="docauthor != ''">
            <xsl:value-of select="docauthor"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="author"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </td>
      <td class="{$tdClass}">
        <xsl:value-of select="revisiondate" />
      </td>
      <td class="{$tdClass}">
        <xsl:value-of select="doclanguage"/>
      </td>
      <td class="{$tdClass}">
        <a>
          <xsl:attribute name="href">
            <xsl:value-of select="sitename" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
          </xsl:attribute>
          <img src="/_layouts/images/breadcrumbbutton.png" style="border-style: none" />
        </a>
        <xsl:call-template name="ShowVersionHistory" />
      </td>
    </tr>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="ShowVersionHistory">

    <!-- First, encode Url -->
    <xsl:variable name="EncodedUrl">
      <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="ddwrt:UrlEncode(url)" />
    </xsl:variable>    

    <!--  does only work for office docuemnts -->
    <xsl:if test="string-length(serverredirectedurl) &gt; 0">

      <!-- get web url from office web app link -->
      <xsl:variable name="WebUrl">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(serverredirectedurl, '_layouts')"/>
      </xsl:variable>

      <!-- create link -->
      <xsl:variable name="FinalLink">
        <xsl:value-of select="$WebUrl"/>
        <xsl:text>_layouts/Versions.aspx?FileName=</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$EncodedUrl"/>
      </xsl:variable>

      <a href="{$FinalLink}" target="_blank" Title="Version History">
        <img src="/_layouts/images/versions.gif" style="border-style: none" />
      </a>
    </xsl:if> 

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <table class="searchresult">
      <tr>
        <th width="18"></th>
        <th>Filename</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Revision Date</th>
        <th>Language</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I only need to get it like Test.dotx or Test.xlsx.
I tried sth with `<xsl:value-of select="substring-after-last($url, '/')" disable-output-escaping="yes" />` but got an error.

What can I do? How can I solve my problem?
Thans for your support.
Kind regards,
Matthias

Comment: XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, and what does the input XML look like?

Comment: Which XSLT version do you use? With XSLT 2.0 you could tokenize and take the last item e.g. `<a href="{tokenize(url, '/')[last()]}"><xsl:value-of select="tokenize(url, '/')[last()]"/></a>`.

Comment: the short version of the XML looks like this: `code`<All_Results> <Result> <id>1</id> <workid>144</workid> <rank>100000000</rank> <title>Test Dokument</title> <author_multival>Test</author_multival> <author>Test</author> <size>34185</size> <url>ht tps://test.test.com/docs/globalit/Lists/Documents/Datumtest/Test.docx</url></Result></All_Results>`code`       (without the space after ht in the url, but it is better to see it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're stuck with XSLT 1.0, you could use a recursive template like this:

#### Stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template name="substring-after-last">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:param name="char"/>

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($string, $char)">
        <xsl:call-template name="substring-after-last">
          <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, $char)"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="char" select="$char"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="substring-after-last">
      <xsl:with-param name="string" select="'/var/log/tomcat'"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="char" select="'/'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### Output

```
tomcat
```

Note, though, that this template probably won't do what you want if the last character in your path is a `/`, because it'll always just return what's after the last `$char`. In other words, for `/var/log/tomcat/` (as opposed to `/var/log/tomcat`, without the trailing forward slash), this template would return an empty string.

To use this in your own code, you could copy-paste the `substring-after-last` template above into your own code and instead of:

```
<xsl:attribute name="href">
  <xsl:value-of select="url" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
</xsl:attribute>
```

You could use:

```
<xsl:attribute name="href">
  <xsl:call-template name="substring-after-last">
    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="url"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="char" select="'/'"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:attribute>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. The path is always a document-path, so it won't endt wit a /. But my question is now: How can I include this code to my code? I started with the XSL few days ago, so my knowledge is not that good.

Comment: I added some instructions into my answer.

Comment: thanks for your additions. what is the difference between `<xsl:output method="text"/>` and `<xsl:output method="xml"/>` I use this XSL in SharePoint and get always an error. I implemented like you said. I can't post more here, I would like to show you my code but it has too much characters.

Comment: You can read up on `xsl:output` for example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256187.aspx). Anyway, the `<xsl:output>` element in my code is just for demo purposes. You can edit your original question to include your full XSLT code.

Comment: Thanks for this tipp. I implemented now your solution, I don't get an error, but I also don't see the filename like `document.docx`, I see nothing. I looked at the XML file and there is the `<url>https://test.test-intranet.com/documents/document.docx<url>` How can I now do the debugging that I know where the problem is?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I can help without seeing your input XML and your full XSLT stylesheet.

Comment: How can I give you these two files?

Comment: As I said before, you can edit your original question to include that information.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I put the XML- and XSL-file to my original question. I hole you can help me. Thanks for your support!!

Comment: @smeets: The code in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/eced3b1d31755aa42925) works for me, at least.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast feedback.
In this case it works, but if your filename has a ü, ä, ö or other special letter it doesn't work. This sepcial letter is not published correct. Just take Hällo.docx as filename. Then you will see the wrong result.

Comment: Try adding `encoding="utf-8"` to our `<xsl:output>` element, like this: `<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>`.

Comment: @smeets: In that case, it's probably some other encoding-related problem. Difficult to see it'd be related to my code. You could try posting another Stack Overflow question with details about your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, you invested a lot of time into my problem, thanks for this. I'll see how I will go on with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a simple, non-recursive XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDoc" select="document('')"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vNodes" select="$vDoc//node()|$vDoc//@*|$vDoc//namespace::*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
   <xsl:variable name="vLength" select="string-length()"/>
   <xsl:variable name="vCur" select="."/>
     <xsl:for-each select="$vNodes[not(position() > $vLength)]">
      <xsl:if test=
       "substring($vCur,$vLength - position()+1,1)='/'
       and not(contains(substring($vCur,$vLength - position()+2), '/'))
       ">
       <xsl:value-of select="substring($vCur,$vLength - position()+2)"/>
      </xsl:if>
     </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<t>http://abc.com/seg1/seg2/seg3/seg4/seg5/filename.html</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
filename.html
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this help. But how can I get your code into my code? I'm not a specialist in XSL, i started few days ago. So I don't really understand what your code is doing.

Comment: @Smeets, Just include the code in an `xsl:variable` -- it will contain `true` or `false` after that -- and youcan then reference this variable. If you are new to XSLT, you need to read a good book -- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online/341589#341589 .

Comment: Hi Dimitre, thanks for you answer, but because I'm net at XSLT, I don't understand how to include the code to a variable and then reference to this variable. Can you maybe help me a bit more with that? Thanks a lot for the tipp with the book.

Comment: @Smeets, The biggest help is to read a good book on XSLT. If you want, please, ask a *new* question on SO about this new problem you are having.