# How to replace a template result into another section of XML

Tags: xslt

Using this XML

```
<!DOCTYPE ADI SYSTEM "ADI.DTD">
<ADI>
<Asset>
<Metadata>
<AMS Asset_Class="title" Asset_ID="HSHT2344862006150001" Asset_Name="HSHT2344862006150001_ALON_HD" Creation_Date="2020-07-07" Description="Alone-title" Product="SVOD" Verb="" Version_Major="1" Version_Minor="0"/>
<App_Data App="MOD" Name="Type" Value="title"/>
<App_Data App="MOD" Name="Title" Value="Alone S7 Ep02 HD"/>
<App_Data App="MOD" Name="Title_Brief" Value="Alone S7 Ep02 HD"/>
<App_Data App="MOD" Name="Category" Value="History/Alone"/>
<App_Data App="MOD" Name="Category" Value="TV Shows/History/Alone"/>
</Metadata>
</Asset>
</ADI>
```

I'm trying to accomplish three things in a XSLT Transformation.

1. Take one of the Category values in App_Data and extract the string after the last "/"
2. Replace Title and Title_Brief Values with the resulting string.
3. Remove the Category lines

I've been able to alter the Category lines down to the string that I want to substitute into the Title and Title_Brief Values using advice [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248057/xsl-just-the-filename-without-the-path) however my result only replaces both Category lines.

This is my XSLT

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" doctype-system="ADI.DTD" method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="substring-after-last">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:param name="char"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($string, $char)">
        <xsl:call-template name="substring-after-last">
          <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, $char)"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="char" select="$char"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/ADI/Asset/Metadata/App_Data[@Name='Category']">
        <xsl:call-template name="substring-after-last">
          <xsl:with-param name="string" select="@Value"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="char" select="'/'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

The result being

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ADI
  SYSTEM "ADI.DTD">
<ADI>
   <Asset>
      <Metadata>
         <AMS Asset_Class="title"
              Asset_ID="HSHT2344862006150001"
              Asset_Name="HSHT2344862006150001_ALON_HD"
              Creation_Date="2020-07-07"
              Description="Alone-title"
              Product="SVOD"
              Verb=""
              Version_Major="1"
              Version_Minor="0"/>
         <App_Data App="MOD" Name="Type" Value="title"/>
         <App_Data App="MOD" Name="Title" Value="Alone S7 Ep02 HD"/>
         <App_Data App="MOD" Name="Title_Brief" Value="Alone S7 Ep02 HD"/>
Alone
Alone
</Metadata>
   </Asset>
</ADI>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xsl:attribute allowed me to accomplish my result, so the last template looks like

```
 <xsl:template match="/ADI/Asset/Metadata/App_Data[@Name='Category']">
    <App_Data App="{@App}" Name="Title">    
      <xsl:attribute name="Value">
        <xsl:call-template name="substring-after-last">
          <xsl:with-param name="string" select="@Value"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="char" select="'/'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </App_Data>
  </xsl:template>
```

Also removing the original Title and Title_Brief with

```
 <xsl:template
    match="/ADI/Asset/Metadata/App_Data[@Name='Title' or @Name='Title_Brief'">
  </xsl:template>
```